# MOSFET as reverse polarity protection and power switch too

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switches, lithium-ion, reverse-polarity

We have a system where there is main power supply as well as a single cell Li-Ion battery (4.1 V to 3.3 V range we'll use) as a backup battery. Its a *low cost and PCB area constrained product*. The idea is when the main supply is off, the system will run off backup battery until an MCU's ADC finds the backup battery voltage low where it needs to cut off the backup battery supply and kill its own power. Next start is when the main supply is back and backup battery is charged.

So the requirement from this question is two folds with respect to backup battery: 1. reverse polarity protection with MOSFET as there is little drop in voltage and 2 MCU control to switch on/off with default as off (with MCU in high impedance).

For reverse polarity protection: a simple PMOS would do since Vgs is low.

**Q1**. The same PMOS can't be used as a control from MCU since the body diode will conduct even if MOSFET is off, right?

For the on/off control from MCU, the simplest I can think of is a PMOS/NMOS pair. The PMOS would be the main switch with NMOS being the control of PMOS's gate with MCU's voltage level controlling NMOS's gate. A resistor is between the G and S of both PMOS and NMOS to keep them off by default.

**Q2** Is this the smallest footprint, low cost on/off control available? Or can there be any other solution which can combine the two requirements?

The MCU's GPIO is not 5V tolerant. So it can't face a voltage of 4.1 V of Li-Ion cell.

Block diagram of what is intended. Note that the question is related to the block with X. Other blocks are working as intended:

[image: Block diagram]

Reverse polarity protection with PMOS as described in Q1:

[image]

Circuit as described in Q2:

[image]

Comment: Don't dismiss a certain component without showing a **schematic**. Switching between power sources can be done using PMOS **if you do that correctly**. I also advise you to **take a step back** and explain in as much detail as you can **what you're trying to achieve**. Add a blockdiagram / schematic. If you (think you) have a certain solution, **draw it**. Often, beginners overcomplicate their solution when much simpler solutions exist. For example: run MCU straight from battery, slowly charge battery when power is available. Often there is no need to actively switch power source.

Comment: _"The MCU's GPIO is not 5V tolerant"_ - so you must be powering the MCU through a regulator, right? Does any other part of the circuit need raw battery voltage? How does the battery get charged?

Comment: What capacity is the Li-ion cell?

Comment: Usually for a load switch with reverse polarity protection you need *two* mosfets back-to-back (sources tied together). Also you can find dedicated micropower stuff for battery powered device (usually using n-channels and charge pumps). Search for 'ideal diode controller'

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoMarcantonio , I'll check.

Comment: Also @Bimpelrekkie I've update the question with relevant details.